# retrieve series of slices of column headers based on truth of dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

consider the dataframe `df`

```
np.random.seed([3,1415])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice((0, 1), (3, 3)),
                  columns=['blah', 'meep', 'zimp'])
df
```

[image]

---

***question***
what is the most efficient way to slice `df.columns` with each row of `df`?
(for this example and at scale)

***expected results***

```
0          [meep]
1          [blah]
2    [blah, zimp]
dtype: object
```

---

## At Scale

I confirmed that @jezrael, @boud, and my answer all produce the same results.  Below is the dataframe I used to test the scale of each solution

```
from string import letters
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(letters), list(letters)])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(52 ** 4).reshape(52 ** 2, -1) % 3 % 2, mux, mux)
```

***setup for boud***

```
s = pd.Series([[x] for x in df], df.columns)
```

***setup for pirsquared***

```
num = df.columns.nlevels
lvls = list(range(num))
rlvls = [x * -1 - 1 for x in lvls]
xsl = lambda x: x.xs(x.name).index.tolist()
```

***results***

[image]

***small df***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) with `list comprehension`:

```
df = df.mul(df.columns.to_series(), axis=1)
print (df)
   blah  meep  zimp
0        meep      
1  blah            
2  blah        zimp

print ([list(filter(None, x)) for x in df.values.tolist()])
[['meep'], ['blah'], ['blah', 'zimp']]

print (pd.Series([list(filter(None, x)) for x in df.values.tolist()], index=df.index))
0          [meep]
1          [blah]
2    [blah, zimp]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Hmmm, I tnink `groupby` solution is very slow... And unfortunately I cannot add timings now

Comment: Thank you, interesting. I thought some other solution can be faster.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `dot` after building a series of atomic lists:

```
s = pd.Series([[col] for col in df.columns])

s.index = df.columns

df.dot(s)
Out[35]: 
0          [meep]
1          [blah]
2    [blah, zimp]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This is exactly one of my clever solutions ;-)

Comment: What's more, you were my motivation for thinking this up

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using sum of products using [`np.sum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) followed by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) as shown:

```
sep = ' '
pd.Series((df.values*(df.columns.values + sep)).sum(1)).str.split()

0          [meep]
1          [blah]
2    [blah, zimp]
dtype: object
```

Comment: great answer!  doesn't generalize to multi-index.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I guess this was tailor-made for the sample `DF` you've provided. Never thought about multi-index situation arising :-)

Answer (score 0):

use `where` and `stack` to drop `0`s then grab indices left over

```
# number of levels in columns
num = df.columns.nlevels
# handy list for stacking
lvls = list(range(num))
# reverse (sort of) list for unstacking
rlvls = [x * -1 - 1 for x in lvls]

# get just levels in index that used to be columns
xsl = lambda x: x.xs(x.name).index.tolist()

# where is faster than replace
# when I stack, I'll drop all np.nan
# then just grab the indices that are left
df.where(df, np.nan).stack(lvls).groupby(level=lvls).apply(xsl)

0          [meep]
1          [blah]
2    [blah, zimp]
dtype: object
```